# Merging n Dictionary instances & execute action on duplicate keys

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to merge an arbitrary amount of Dictionary instances, if a key occurs multiple times I want to execute an action, e.g. `currentResultValue += newFoundValue`.

Sample context: Map/Reduce pattern, reduce step, I counted the occurences of words in a really big text and had 10 mappings, each returning a `Dictionary<string, int>`. In the reduce call I now want to merge all those dictionaries into one.

Example input:

```
Dictionary 1:
    "key1" -> 5
    "key2" -> 3

Dictionary 2:
    "key2" -> 1

Dictionary 3:
    "key1" -> 2
    "key3" -> 17
```

Expected result:

```
"key1" -> 7
"key2" -> 4
"key3" -> 17
```

I'd prefer a LINQ-based solution, e.g. something like:

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, int>> myDictionaries = ...;
myDictionaries.Reduce((curValue, newValue) => curValue + newValue);
```

Do I have to write my extension method myself or is something like that already existing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "key1", 5 }, { "key2", 3 } };
var d2 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "key2", 1 } };
var d3 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "key1", 2 }, { "key3", 17 } };


var dict = new[] { d1, d2, d3 }.SelectMany(x => x)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(y => y.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = myDictionaries.SelectMany(x=>x)
                           .GroupBy(d=>d.Key)
                           .Select(g=> new KeyValuePair<string,int>(g.Key, g.Sum(x=>x.Value)))
                           .ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,v=>v.Value);
```

Comment: Have you tried this? d is of type IDictionary and does not provide a `d.Key` property.

Comment: I'm ok with the edit, however, I4V's answer seems to be a little bit simpler, which is why I'm going to accept his answer. Upvote for your effort though.

Comment: @D.R. no, just accept the better answer, I think the answer of `I4V` is very good.